# counterexamples for preserves equalizer if and only if preserves pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, functors

Assume $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are two categories where finite products exist, then I have proved that if a functor $F: \mathcal{C}\rightarrow \mathcal{D}$ preserves finite products, then we have $F$ preserves equalizer if and only if $F$ preserves pullback diagram.

Then I want to ask if this holds without the condition that $F$ preserves finite products. If the answer is no, I want to know the counterexamples for the “if” part and the "only if " part respectively.

Thanks!

Comment: You also need to assume that $C$ has finite products.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan.  Yes, thank you.

Comment: Can you summarize the last proof you mentioned? For a counterexample, perhaps you could define $F$ to merge two specific objects to cause a specific pullback solution to no longer be the limit, i.e., turn a *specific* pullback into an equalizer in a way that makes a different cone more optimal. This assumes that those two objects aren't used in any equalizers.

Comment: @KevinP.Barry  If $\mathcal{C}$ has finite products, then in $\mathcal{C}$, there is a correspondence between equalizers and pullback diagrams(proposition 5.7 in [this book](https://books.google.fr/books?id=IK_sIDI2TCwC&lpg=PP1&hl=zh-CN&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false)), and I think it is enough to see  $F$ preserves equalizer iff $$ preserves pullback diagram.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a partially ordered set as a category $\mathcal{C}$. Since there is at most one morphism between any two objects in $\mathcal{C}$, equalisers exist but are always trivial, and any functor out of $\mathcal{C}$ will preserve equalisers. On the other hand, pullbacks may or may not exist in $\mathcal{C}$, and may or may not be preserved by functors out of $\mathcal{C}$. Therefore a functor that preserves equalisers may not preserve pullbacks.

It is more difficult to construct a functor that preserves pullbacks but not equalisers, because one can construct equalisers using pullbacks and "very weak" coequalisers. More precisely, given a parallel pair $X \rightrightarrows Y$, if there is a morphism $Y \to Z$ such that the two composites $X \rightrightarrows Y \to Z$ are equal – no universality, not even weak universality, required – then we can construct the equaliser of $X \rightrightarrows Y$ as the pullback of $Y \to Y \times_Z Y$ along $X \to Y \times_Z Y$. In a category $\mathcal{D}$ where every parallel pair has a "very weak" coequaliser, such as a category with a terminal object, any functor out of $\mathcal{D}$ that preserves pullbacks will automatically preserve equalisers as well. (Any functor whatsoever preserves "very weak" coequalisers.)

There should be a counterexample but it seems to be more fiddly than I first imagined. Perhaps I will add one if I figure out an easy one.